# How to prevent a click event using jQuery.live

Tags: live, jquery

When I use the following jquery live function

```
$("a[rel]").live('click', function () {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked');
});
```

`e.preventDefault();` does not work, because the action behind the `a` tag is still fired.

How do I **prevent an event** when I use **jQuery.live**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the e inside the function argument list.

```
$("a[rel]").live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked');
});
```

You could also try adding

```
return false;
```

to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `e` argument to the function, try this:

```
$("a[rel]").live('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('clicked');
});
```